# SQLITE firing query to search with a non primary key value

Tags: sqlite

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
    AUTOINCREMENT, KEY_PNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_LOC + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + KEY_TH + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
```

Now suppose I have to extract the value of `KEY_ROWID` of a particular value of `KEY_LOC`.then what query should I fire on database because in my app if I have a location's `latitude` `longtitude(KEY_LOC)`. I should be able to show rest of the data associated with that location.

Comment: public String getPNAME(long l) throws SQLException{
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_PNAME, KEY_LOC,KEY_TH};
   Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_LOC + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
   
   if (c != null){
    c.moveToFirst();
    String n = c.getString(2);
    //long name=Long.parseLong(n);
    
    return n;
   }
   return null;
  }

this was my method to get value of KEY_PNAME from its associated valueof  KEY_LOC
But its not working

Comment: And what is wrong with that?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the additional information in a more readable shape. And please make an MCVE, which should include a `.dump` of the database.